# Casting int to enum value in razor view

Tags: c#, razor, enums

I have an enum that looks like this:

```
public enum SMSTaskStatus
{
    New = 0,
    Awaiting = 1,
    InProgress = 2,
    OnHold = 3,
    Done = 4,
    Error = 5
}
```

and I am trying to return the value in a razor view using

```
<td>@{ (SMSTaskStatus) item.Status.Value;}</td>
```

but i get an error that

```
'Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await and new
 object expressions can be used as a statement'
```

How can I cast it to the enum value in the view? It's a nullable int in my class

```
public int? Status { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned before when you try to cast an enum in razor, you get the error.
I tried to implement your situation, I think this could be a good solution:
In razor :

```
@{var currentStatus = (SMSTaskStatus) item.Status;}

<td>@currentStatus</td>
```